# How to plot points over a violin plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I have four pandas Series and I plot them using a violin plot as follows:

```
import seaborn
seaborn.violinplot([X1['total'], X2['total'], X3['total'], X4['total']])
```

I would like to plot the values on top of the violin plot so I added:

```
seaborn.stripplot([X1['total'], X2['total'], X3['total'], X4['total']])
```

But this gives:

[image]

It plots all the points over the first violin plot.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (seaborn `0.12.1`), `sns.violinplot` seems to accept a list of lists as data, and interprets it similar to a wide form dataframe.  `sns.striplot` (as well as `sns.swarmplot`), however, interpret this as a single dataset.

On the other hand, `sns.stripplot` accepts a dictionary of lists and interprets it as a wide form dataframe.  But `sns.violinplot` refuses to work with that dictionary.

Note that seaborn is being actively reworked internally to allow a wider set of data formats, so one of the future versions will tackle this issue.

So, a list of lists for the violin plot, and a dictionary for the stripplot allows combining both:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X1, X2, X3, X4 = [pd.DataFrame({'total': np.random.normal(.1, 1, np.random.randint(99, 300)).cumsum()})
                  for _ in range(4)]

ax = sns.violinplot([X1['total'], X2['total'], X3['total'], X4['total']], inner=None)
sns.stripplot({0: X1['total'], 1: X2['total'], 2: X3['total'], 3: X4['total']},
              edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, palette=['white'] * 4, ax=ax)
```

[image: combining sns.violinplot and sns.stripplot]